# Adding bounds variable to netcdf file

Tags: python, netcdf, nco

I would like to add latitude bounds to an existing netCDF file. See `http://www.cgd.ucar.edu/cms/eaton/netcdf/CF-20010629.htm#bnds` for definition of bounds.

Is there a command that can add bounds automatically? I am open to any solution using nco or netCDF4 or cdms toolkit. However, I would prefer it to be a post processing solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add bounds to an existing coordinate like this:

```
ncap2 -O -s 'crd@bounds="crd_bnds";defdim("bnds",2);crd_bnds[$crd,$bnds]=0.0;*crd_dff=0.5*(crd(1)-crd(0));crd_bnds(:,0)=crd-crd_dff;crd_bnds(:,1)=crd+crd_dff;' in.nc out.nc
```

This yields

```
zender@aerosol:~$ ncks --cdl -v crd ~/foo2.nc
netcdf foo2 {
  dimensions:
    bnds = 2 ;
    crd = 10 ;

  variables:
    int crd(crd) ;
      crd:bounds = "crd_bnds" ;

    double crd_bnds(crd,bnds) ;

  data:
    crd = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ;

    crd_bnds = -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.5, 6.5, 6.5, 7.5, 7.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9.5 ;

} // group /
```

Here the coordinate is named "crd", and the bounds are named "crd_bnds". The formula for the bounds values can be simple when the coordinate changes by a fixed value (as above), or more involved to account for variable spacing (exercise for reader). We will add an ncap2 function to do this automatically in the near future.

cz

Comment: FYI Latest snapshot of ncap2 has a new function to create CF-compliant bounds:
   defdim("bnd_dmn",2);
   bounds_var=make_bounds(crd_var,$bnd_dmn,"bounds_var_nm");
   The "bounds_var_nm" is optional. Passing it causes make_bounds() to 
   add the attribute crd_var@bounds="bounds_var_nm".
   http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#make_bounds