# how to include the time_bnds 1981-01-01 00:00 -1981-01-01 23:00 in a nc file using cdo?

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a NC file with 13879 daily time steps starting from 1981-01-01. I want to include "time_bnds" in a 1981-01-01 00:00-1981-01-01 23:00 format. How do I do that with cdo? I am attaching two NC files, one of which needs this "time_bnds" and the other contains the required time_bnds.
The one in which time_bnds is required to be included is named

1. imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped.nc

The other one, which is in correct format (already have the time_bnds),

2. pr_1981_2018_clipped_mm.nc

Please advise on how to add the time_bnds to the imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped.nc file, as mentioned above.

The link for the data is
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W-88fLjbw-L0m9hHNNmT-44xt9h5sehI/view?usp=gmail)

Comment: I have answered the Q given the info given. However, the Q is rather unclear. What do you mean by "1981-01-01 00:00-1981-01-01 23:00 format"? In netCDF you can specify the time and things like the bounds, which would specify the start and end period a timestamp covers. So your question can be interpreted in various ways.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. After reading your comment, I now realize that it should be time bounds (time_bnds). I am sorry that I wasted your valuable time by posting an incorrect question. Can you kindly suggest me how to incorporate the time_bnds in the nc file?

Comment: Can you just rewrite the question? Posting the original question with an edit is confusing to anyone reading the question for the first time. Just tell us what you need answered and leave it at that

Comment: Thank you, sir. I have rewritten the question.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with CDO. You can probably do it with NCO. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665848/adding-bounds-variable-to-netcdf-file

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I got a solution from the CDO forum. As you correctly pointed out, it cannot be done by CDO; it requires NCO. The solution to my question is:

ncap2 -O -s 'defdim("bnds",2);time_bnds=make_bounds(TIME,$bnds,"time_bnds");' \imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped.nc imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped_changed.nc

Comment: Can you post that as an answer to the question? This would help others

Comment: Sure. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to thank Robert Wilson and Karin Meier-Fleischer of the CDO support forum for their help. As pointed out by Robert Wilson, it cannot be done using CDO but can be achieved by NCO.
I got the solution to my question from Karin Meier-Fleischer in the CDO support forum, which is as follows:

```
ncap2 -O -s 'defdim("bnds",2);time_bnds=make_bounds(TIME,$bnds,"time_bnds");' \imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped.nc imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped_changed.nc
```

The link to the CDO forum is [here](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/15224?r=15231)

Answer (score 1):

The CDO method you are looking for in this case is `shifttime`.

You will need to move time forward 23 hours, which can be done as follows:

```
cdo shifttime,23hours in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer; however, this command is not giving me the desired result. The timestamp is not changing.
It is still showing 1981-01-01
What I need is 
1981-01-01 00:00-1981-01-01 23:00

Comment: Please double check. It works for me. What command are you running and how are you checking the time stamps?

Comment: I am checking it with panoply. I am unable to attach the screenshots here.
I am using the command:
cdo shifttime,23hours imd_pr_1981_2018_clipped.nc out2.nc.

Comment: Try `cdo showtimestamp`. I'm not familiar with panoply, but it looks like all it does is show the date, not the time

Comment: The first and last two timesteps from the cdo showtimetimestamp command is as follows:
first two: 1981-01-01T23:00:00  1981-01-02T23:00:00
last two: 2018-12-30T23:00:00  2018-12-31T23:00:00.

Is it same as 1981-01-01 00:00-1981-01-01 23:00?

Comment: I don't follow. The original file has daily data with the time of 00:00 each day. My understanding of the original question is that you wanted time to be 23:00. Is this wrong?

Comment: Thank you, Sir. After reading your comment, I now realize that it should be time bounds (time_bnds). I am sorry that I wasted your valuable time by posting an incorrect question. Can you kindly suggest how to incorporate the time_bnds in the nc file?
I am now editing the question